# Trouble in Dual boot get stuck load screen

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, 17.04, usb-installation, kde5

I have a Asus x550vb(**Laptop**) with Windows 10 and i try make dual boot (windows+kde neon).

**Bios (EFI) Setup:**

- **OS:** Windows 10 pro x64 HDD 1 TB
- Fast Startup and Secure Boot are disabled.
- Free space on my hard drive(230 GB).
- Boot Mode: EFI / Partition table: GPT.
- CSM/legacy options are disabled.

I followed these steps:

1. I formatted my partition table(GPT).
2. I clean-installed Windows 10 with default partitions:

   - A Recovery partition.
   - An EFI System Partition.
   - A Microsoft Reserved Partition.
   - A Windows Data Partition or C drive.
3. Create another partition(NTFS) for data. [Partition Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upXvQ.png)
4. I made a bootable USB Stick with Kde neon 5.10.90 from ISO, using Rufus.
5. boot from the USB stick, I'm offered with the choice of kde neon or Kde neon(OEM) but i have a trouble in the loading screen is stuck.[stuck load screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok67v.png)

**PD:** I try with Partition table(MBR) and dont stuck load screen but i want in GPT partition.

Comment: While loading press <kbd>F12</kbd> to see what is the error and post it

Comment: @Arun I press **F12** but  nothing happens.

Comment: Ok. When you are in grub menu press e and remove the words quiet and splash and then boot

Comment: @Arun Sry, i press F12 beggining load and fix stuck loader.

Comment: You fixed the problem?

Comment: @Arun Yes, i fixed temporaly the problem stuck loader screen, but after install kde neon again stuck in loader.

Comment: @Arun Could it be a driver problem?

Comment: @Arun thx for all, I fixed enter in nomodeset and update nvidia drivers